# Partial View does not compile properly in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, partial-views, directive

```
// Code goes here
var mymodule = angular.module('myapp', []);
mymodule.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope) {

});

mymodule.directive('pvTempUrl',
    function ($http, $compile, $log, $templateCache) {
        $log.info("Directive Called");
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            compile: function (telement, tattr, transclude) {
                var templateloader = $http.get(tattr.pvTempUrl, { cache: $templateCache }).
                    success(function (data) {
                        $log.info("Success-" + data);
                        telement.html(data);
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status) {
                        $log.warn("Error occured - " + data + " status-" + status);
                    });
                return function (scope, element, attr) {
                    templateloader.then(function () {
                        var compiledHtm = ($compile(telement.html())(scope)).html();
                        $log.info("compiled html-" + compiledHtm);
                        element.html(compiledHtm);
                    });
                }; 
            }
        };
    });
```

I have a partial page trying to compile the page is working just showing the template as such.

Plunkr is avaliable here

http://plnkr.co/edit/U85rmXhuQGKx5pkzUu99?p=preview

Issue found i was binding the html not the compiled object resolved the issue like below

```
// Code goes here
var mymodule = angular.module('myapp', []);
mymodule.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope) {

});

mymodule.directive('pvTempUrl',
    function ($http, $compile, $log, $templateCache) {
        $log.info("Directive Called");
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            compile: function (telement, tattr, transclude) {
                var templateloader = $http.get(tattr.pvTempUrl, { cache: $templateCache }).
                    success(function (data) {
                        $log.info("Success-" + data);
                        telement.html(data);
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status) {
                        $log.warn("Error occured - " + data + " status-" + status);
                    });
                return function (scope, element, attr) {
                    templateloader.then(function () {
                        var compiledHtm = ($compile(telement.html())(scope));
                        $log.info("compiled html-" + compiledHtm);
                        //element.html(compiledHtm);
                        element.replaceWith(compiledHtm);
                         $log.info(element.html());
                    });
                }; 
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: how did you solve this?  please post the solution for us

Comment: solution present in a plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anyone try to load a template this way before. The proper Angular ways of loading a template are the following:

- Using `ng-view` to load a predefined template file.
- Building your own custom directive.

I feel like you are attempting to do the second method. The following code sample is an example of how to do that.

```
angular.module("myapp")
.directive('buttonsRadio', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    controller: function($scope){
        //Any logic required for directive to work.    
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
};
})
```

In your template.html file you would have your template you wish to load.

For much more detail and examples on how to build your own custom directive elements, see the section [Writing Directives (long version)](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) in the Angular docs.

*UPDATE: Edited to show example of templateUrl.*

Comment: i need a templateUrl example in custom directive instead of template(hard coded HTML)

Comment: thanks jbw91 i am already aware of this but my requirement is i need to load the template according to the url url will be the part of the directive.
<buttons-Radio temp-Url="template.html"></buttons-Radio>
like this.